# Ruby Net::SCP download asking for password then failing

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to download a file to an in-memory buffer from a unix box then upload the file to another unix box, but when I try to download the file it asks for my password then fails even if I put it in. I've tried both:

```
data = Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username", "/remote/path", :password => password)
```

and

```
data = Net::SCP::download!("remote.host.com", "username", "/remote/path", :password => password)
```

but I get:

```
Active Directory Password:
```

Then when I enter my password:

```
Net::SCP::Error: SCP did not finish successfully (1)
```

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]
net-scp (1.0.4)

Comment: pass in `:verbose => true` and see what happens

Comment: Same results as before, thanks for your response!  I've explored a solution using Net::SFTP that works but I'm still curious about why Net::SCP does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use it like this:

```
require 'net/scp'

data = nil
Net::SCP.start("remote.host.com", "username", :password => "password") do |scp|
  data = scp.download!("/remote/path")
end

puts data
```

**EDIT:** I only tried this on ruby ruby-1.9.3, sorry

Comment: This does work, it looks exactly the same as the solution I've developed using Net::SFTP which is interesting.  However when I want to upload that file on a server SCP won't be able to do it as with SFTP I have to do `sftp.file.open("filepath", 'w') { |f| f.puts data end}`  SCP doesn't have `.file`

Comment: yeah, sftp is probably the right thing for what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Net::SFTP will be what I'm actually going to use, its not much more and is probably what I'd end up with anyway since I didn't realize I need to 'write' the `@data` before putting it on another server.

```
data = nil
Net::SFTP.start('remoteHost1', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  data = sftp.download!("filepath1")
end

Net::SFTP.start('remoteHost2', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  sftp.file.open("filePath2", "w") do |f|
    f.puts data
  end
end
```